# .NET Core Task.Delay() consume processor

Tags: c#, .net

.NET Core (2, 3) Task.Delay() consume 55% of the quad-core processor. I don’t understand whether this is normal or not. And if it’s not normal, where to look for the reason. Test code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
            Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is not waiting on the delay. Instead your code is creating Delay tasks as rapidly as it can that are never awaited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not delaying, you need to `await` that call.

Try adding some Console.WriteLine and you will see that your code does not wait in the delay.
Here another version using async and await. This one waits:

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("starting the loop");
                
                Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("this is printed inmediately, previous delay does not stop the execution");
                
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("this happens 1 second later, the previous delay is awaited");
            }
        }
    }
```

Try it online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sCT80H

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Task.Delay requires an await. If you don't await then the loop runs without any pause (like if Delay was not there) and that is why you see a lot of CPU being consumed